# Side by side spinners in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am having trouble with spinners breaking the GridLayout. I have seen a solution to use the following to stop spinners from breaking the bounds of the screen

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

However, when I try and place two spinners side by side I get the following

[image]

```
<TextView
    android:layout_columnSpan="4"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/vessel_type"
    android:id="@+id/vessel_type" />

<TextView
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"

    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />

<Spinner

    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2" />
```

Is there a way around this or should I go back to linearlayouts?

Comment: Have you tried the layout in a real app on a device? Sometimes the layout editor does not show everything right.

Comment: @Ridcully it looks better on my nexus but still not the perfect grid I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify layout_column and layout_columnSpan for spinner2? 
It might also be helpful to see the whole layout file.